# Leverage Caching of Static Assets

Tags: html, caching, cdn

I understand that you can set up caching on your own webserver, but how do you leverage caching of static assets for CDNs. For example

```
FAILED - (No max-age or expires) - http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif
FAILED - (No max-age or expires) - http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans
```

and files being hosted on my Amazon S3 are also not caching

My HTML looks like

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Copy-Paste the font ( or font family ) CSS file.

2.Put the resulting FLAT CSS file at a location & naming convention of your choosing, somewhere within your web app or a centralized known location that you can always get to.

3.Download each of the .ttf files, rename them according to some sensible convention, inclluding the actual ".ttf" file extension. The mime-type should be included in the binary of the file itself. ( This is a good theory. If any knows how to test it let me know. )

4.Place those, again, somewhere sensible that you can access. A "ttf/" directory in the directory that you placed that CSS file in step 2 seems pretty darn reasonable to me.

5.Edit the CSS to reflect the new URL's of those .ttf's instead of Google's "dynamicized" URL's.

6.Edit the original CSS include to reflect the new location of your flat CSS file.
Enjoy fast download times on Web Fonts.